# Can external email (gmail in this case) recipients view internal "private" emails within the same email thread?

Tags: google-chrome, email, gmail, privacy

The situation is such:

1. Email thread started with external recipients (outside an office)...let's call them E1 and E2, and I1, I2, and I3 ("I" internal and "E" for external recipients).
2. After a few emails, I1, I2 and I3 have a few "private" emails (no external recipients) but still within the same email thread (so all external emails are visible).
3. This is followed by another email with the external participants (E1 and E2, and all of internal participants.

In this last email, all the convos (both external and internal) are visible to me. The question is, are the emails that were meant to be private also visible to the external recipients?

Comment: Clarify where you fit into this: `I1`?

Answer (score 0):

##### Maybe

It depends on whether you are looking at the content in the email, or content that is being dynamically merged for you by your email client when you open the email in threaded messaging.

There are a couple of approaches to determining what you are looking at.  The most reliable will be to look at the original version of the email.

1. In Gmail, open the email you received (or sent)
2. Click the kebob menu (3-dots), next to the **Reply** icon,  select **Show original**
   [image]
3. Review the message content for previous messages